# Function that assigns names to a struct using strtok

Tags: c

I worked around using `strtok` function so to assign first name and last name to a `struct PERSONNE` from a `char *names[]` array. It was not possible to directly modify the `*names[]` using `strtok` since it was throwing an exception.

This code works fine but the last loop shows a lot of `'\n'` until it reaches 10. I am unable to set the unused data in `p1` to NULL. Is it bad practice to not set unused structure data to NULL?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define u_short             unsigned short
#define u_int               unsigned int

#define bool                int
#define true                1
#define false               0

#define MAX                 10

typedef struct PERSONNE
{
    int id;
    char nom[MAX];
    char prenom[MAX];
}personne, *p_personne;

char *names[]={
                "HARRY JANDU",
                "LIBNI MACTAVISH",
                "DIMPLE CHOWDARI",
                "PRIYA MOHAN",
                NULL
            };

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    personne p1[10];
    memset(&p1, 0, sizeof(p1));       // doesn't set to 0
    for( i=0; i<sizeof(names); i++ )
    {
        if( names[i]==NULL )break;
        char *temp=NULL, *pch=NULL;
        temp=(char*)malloc(strlen(names[i]));
        strcpy(temp, names[i]);
        pch=strtok(temp, " ");
        strcpy(p1[i].prenom, pch);
        while( pch!=NULL )
        {
            strcpy(p1[i].nom, pch);
            pch=strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }

    printf("FIRST NAME\tLastName\n");
//  printf("%d\n", p1[0]);
    for( i=0; i<10; i++ )
    {
        if( p1[i].nom==0 )break;
        printf("%s\t\t%s\n", p1[i].prenom, p1[i].nom);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I see some things that may help you improve your code.

### Use whitespace to improve readability

Lines like this:

```
for( i=0; i<sizeof(names); i++ )
```

become easier to read with a bit more whitespace:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(names); i++)
```

### Prefer `++i` to `i++` in loops

There is not a big difference for most uses, but if you don't need to save the pre-incremented value, make it simple for both the reader and the compiler and say `++i`.  This also will help when you start using C++ iterators which often only implement the prefix `++` operator.

### Declare the loop exit condition at the top

The code currently contains these lines:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(names); i++) {
    if (names[i] == NULL)
        break;
```

So the `for` loop claims that the loop exits when `i >= sizeof(names)` but the following line says we exit when `names[i] == NULL`.  In this program, only latter is actually used, so the loop should be written to reflect that:

```
for (i = 0; names[i] != NULL; i++) {
```

Similarly, the printing loop can be simplified:

```
for (i = 0; p1[i].prenom[0]; ++i) {
    printf("%s\t\t%s\n", p1[i].prenom, p1[i].nom);
}
```

### Eliminate unused variables

Unused variables are a sign of poor code quality, so eliminating them should be a priority.  In this code, `j` is defined but not used. Your compiler is probably also smart enough to tell you that, if you ask it to do so.  Also, the code includes a number of unused `#define`s, one unused `typedef` and one unused `struct` member, all of which just add to clutter in the code.

### Use only required `#include`s

The code has `#include <time.h>` but nothing from that header is used.  This clutters the code and makes it more difficult to read and understand.  Only include files that are actually needed.

### Use const where practical

The current code does not  modify the `names` array, and so it should be declared `const`:

```
const char const *names[] = {
```

### Use `stdbool`

Instead of defining your own values for `true` and `false`, you might consider instead using `#include <stdbool.h>` which defines `true` and `false`.  However, in this program, neither is used.

### Free memory that you allocate

This program leaks memory because you have allocated space using `malloc` but never released with `free`.  That's bad practice.

### Eliminate useless code

The code currently contains this loop:

```
while (pch != NULL) {
    strcpy(p1[i].nom, pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

This has the effect of copying each word in the name and only saving the last one which is not very efficient.  See the next suggestion for a more efficient means.

### Use the appropriate library function

Instead of copying the string and using `strtok`, I'd recommend that the code should use `strchr`.

```
for (i = 0; names[i] != NULL; i++) {
    char *pch = strchr(names[i], ' ');
    if (pch == NULL || pch-names[i] > MAX) {
        strncpy(p1[i].prenom, names[i], MAX);
    } else {
        strncpy(p1[i].prenom, names[i], pch-names[i]);
        strncpy(p1[i].nom, pch, MAX);
    }
    p1[i].nom[MAX-1] = '\0';
    p1[i].prenom[MAX-1] = '\0';
}
```

Note too, that this code uses the safer `strncpy` and also assures that each string is properly terminated with `'\0'`.

### Make sure your data structures are big enough

With only 10 characters allocated for both `nom` and `prenom`, many names simply won't fit. "Ludwig van Beethoven" is one such example.

### Eliminate `return 0` at the end of `main`

Since C99, the compiler automatically generates the code corresponding to `return 0` at the end of `main` so there is no need to explicitly write it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Bug

You allocated one too few bytes here:

> ```
>     temp=(char*)malloc(strlen(names[i]));
>     strcpy(temp, names[i]);
> ```

You need to also allocate one extra byte for the null terminating character.  Right now you are writing past the end of `temp` by one byte.  This code should have been:

```
    temp=(char*)malloc(strlen(names[i]) + 1);
    strcpy(temp, names[i]);
```

#### Bug 2

Your loop doesn't loop the correct amount of times:

> ```
> for( i=0; i<sizeof(names); i++ )
> ```

`sizeof(names)` will be the size of the array of *pointers*, which means that if a pointer has size 4, this will be 4 times the number of entries (5), or 20 in your case.

This should have been:

```
for( i=0; i<sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0]); i++ )
```

This will loop 20 / 4 = 5 times, which is the actual number of entries in the array.  The reason your program works is because you added the extra check:

> ```
>     if( names[i]==NULL )break;
> ```

I wonder if you added that because your program crashed otherwise.

#### Unsafe copy

This string copy is unsafe because your buffer is a fixed length (10) and the string you are copying is an unknown length.

```
        strcpy(p1[i].nom, pch);
```

You can copy it safely by using `strncpy` to do the copy:

```
        strncpy(p1[i].nom, pch, MAX-1);
        p1[i].nom[MAX-1] = '\0';
```

There is also the same problem for `prenom` as well.